# выбор массива по значению в многомерном массиве

Tags: php, массивы

Есть многомерный массив:

```
$array = array(
   array(
      'device'=>'iphone',
      'title'=>'айфон',
   ),
   array(
      'device'=>'samsung',
      'title'=>'самсунг',
   ),
);
```

Необходимо найти вложенный массив по значению device==samsung, чтобы вытягивать именно из этого вложенного массива параметры title и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простой фп-подход

```
function getDeviceSpec($specList, $deviceName) {
    foreach ($specList as $spec) {
        if ($spec['device'] === $name) {
            return $spec;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

использование

```
$samsungSpec = getDeviceSpec($array, 'samsung');
```

обращаю внимание, что эта конструкция может и не найти данные и вернуть `null`, если такого устройства нет.

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно, что обычный перебор решит вашу проблему:

```
foreach ($array as $item) {
    if ($item['device'] == 'samsung') {
        print $item['title'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мы простых путей не ищем:

```
$title = array_values(array_filter($array, function ($i) { return $i['device'] == 'samsung'; }))[0]['title'];
```

Ну или:

```
$title = array_values(
    array_filter(
        $array,
        function ($i) {
            return $i['device'] == 'samsung';
        }
    )
)[0]['title'];
```

Также можете воспользоваться [YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo) моего производства:

```
$title = from($array)->single('$v["device"] == "samsung"')['title'];
```

Comment: Тоже может вернуться null (а что еще забавней, php это [без проблем съест](http://govnokod.ru/16666)).

Comment: @Etki Я тут cижу сочиняю самый бесполезный ответ, которым ОП гарантированно не воспользуется, а вы берёте и его проверяете. :)) Проверил, первая версия (и она же вторая) вылетает с notice (array_filter вернёт пустой массив, я так понимаю). Последняя версия корректно отработает — выбросится исключение.

Comment: Я не проверял. На 5.3 нет дереференса элемента массива на возвращаемом значении, может, из-за этого.

Comment: @Etki 5.3? Зачем так жить? %) Его же даже не поддерживают скоро год как.

Comment: я не знаю у кого какая версия стоит, поэтому предполагаю возможность наличия 5.3. ubuntu 12.04 LTS не умеет из коробки в 5.4, centos по-моему даже новый не умеет, несколько раз сталкивался, очень частая ситуация, когда есть пятилетняя VPS с пятью проектами, и шестой не должен это дело затронуть. С какой-то центос аналогичную проблему решили просто проксей на мой впс, потому что там даже докер из-за древности ядра было не поднять.

Comment: Лично я потерялся от обилия умных слов... `:)`

Comment: @VisioN Вы про последнее сообщение Etki? TL;DR: оси обновляются медленно, новые версии осей поставляются со старым PHP, на хостингах вообще всё тухло, работоспособность старого кода превыше всего, из-за этого повсеместно используются ископаемые версии PHP (и других приложений, в том числе для разворачивания приложений), в которых не поддерживаются современные фичи языка, что приводит к нескончаемой боли и нагромождениям костылей.

Comment: @Athari Да, про последнее сообщение. Докер, прокси на VPS... даже представить себе такое не могу. Насчет хостингов полностью согласен: дождаться от админов обновления ПО на общем сервере зачастую невозможно. Никто не хочет брать ответственность за отвалившиеся сайты клиентов. Но вот касательно VPS я не согласен. Человек арендующий VPS полностью отвечает за обновление ОС и ПО на этом VPS. И если у кого-то на VPS стоит ископаемая версия PHP вкупе с древним ядром, и несчастные 5 проектов рискуют перманентно сдохнуть после обновления ОС, значит либо проекты дрянь, либо сами понимаете.

Comment: @VisioN Или пора заиметь два VPS...

Comment: @VisioN эт хорошо, но что делать, когда такая ситуация возникла? Там вообще за два часа надо было весь деплой осуществить. Ну и легаси-проекты тоже надо как-то итеративно обновлять, все что я пишу - пишу 5.3-compliant.

Comment: вообщем-то если конструкция данные не найдет, то это нормально. у меня так и должно быть по определению. Вот только эти `null` не помешают ли мне при выводе значений, сейчас задумался..
А так спасибо, конечно)